Apache eCharts - stacking/unstacking rearranges bars
I have a set of data that are originally presented as bars grouped by month. I have a button that stacks/unstacks the bars by simply assigning them the same stacking word to stack them or assigning them an index to unstack. The data themselves are never changed, they remain in the same order in an array of categories, and each month's data points remain in the same places in an array corresponding to months within the categories.
Here's the code that actually does the stacking/unstacking. The call to setOptions at the bottom of the function triggers the echart automatic redraw.

An example:

so in this example, I have 15 categories and it's after stacking, so the stack variables are all "stackMe!". The data field has months 0, 1, and 2.
So far, so good. When the data is first loaded as unstacked, bars are in the proper order. Here's what it looks like for the middle month, where the first category is 13 and the second is 1.

Things remain in order after stacking (the little slice with 1 is too thin to see here, but it's there) (...also, yes, I know it's impossible to read those data labels, it's what my client wants and I hate it but they pay me):

but then when I push the button to unstack them again, the 13 moves to the end of the group:

Seems like it's probably an off-by-one error, but the data is the exact same as it was before the stacking:

I've tried re-sorting the categories and re-sorting the data within each category, but no luck. Additionally, if I stack them a second time, the 13 is on the bottom where it belongs, it doesn't somehow end up on top next to the 12. So the data is presumably in the way it should be.
Anybody have any idea what might be going on? I could delete and redraw the entire chart, I guess, but that would flicker on the screen and look weird. And I shouldn't have to go to that extreme, that's a silly way to fix the problem. There must be a better way.

Pls share all relevant code and not as image. With the current information I am not able to reproduce your problem. See the example below.

Example

Also echarts has built in support for stacking/unstacking: Example

Thanks, Matthias, that example lead me to find a fix. Instead of assigning it a stack value of index when unstacking, I assigned it undefined and the problem was fixed. In your example graph, I can reproduce the original behavior by changing the assignment that you have to undefined over to (for example)
 if (bool) {     series = series.map(x => {return {stack: x}})     bool = false;   }
Not really sure why it's happening, but I suppose all I really care about is that undefined works.

TL;DR
If you want to remove the stack from a serie, set its value to null (or undefined).
How to work stacking in ECharts
With the series-bar.stack value, you can change the current state both before and after rendering the chart.
The text passed to the stack property must be consistent for all series that you want to merge. If you need multiple groups, you simply need to use different stack names for each group. In my example, I divided a total of 4 series into 2 stacks. If you want to group all series into a single stack, you just need to set the same name for the stack property of all 4 series.
If you want to remove the stack from a serie, set its value to null (or undefined).


/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom);

/**
 ** Data
 */
const categoryData = ['category0', 'category1', 'category2', 'category3', 'category4'];
const barData = [30, 50, 70, 60, 80];

/**
 ** Option
 */
const option = {
  legend: {},
  yAxis: {},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: categoryData,
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'firstSerieName',
      data: barData,
      stack: 'firstStackName',
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'secondSerieName',
      data: barData,
      stack: 'secondStackName',
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'thirdSerieName',
      data: barData,
      stack: 'secondStackName',
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'fouthSerieName',
      data: barData,
      stack: 'firstStackName',
    },
  ]
};

/**
 ** Render Chart
 */
chart.setOption(option);

/**
 ** Track original stack names from option.series
 */
const originalStacks = option.series.map(series => series.stack);

/**
 ** Change series stack status by external function
 */
document.getElementById('toggleStack').addEventListener('click', () => {  
  option.series.forEach((series, index) => {
    const isStacked = series.stack !== null
    
    // if stacked ? remove stack : set original stack name
    series.stack = isStacked ? null : originalStacks[index];
  });
  chart.setOption(option, true);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-k37wQcV4v2h6jgYf5IUz1MoSKPpDs630XGSmCaCCOXxy2awgAWKHGZWr9nMyGgk3IOxA1NxdkN8r1JHgkUtMoQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button id="toggleStack">Toggle bar stack</button>

<div id="chart" style="width: 650px; height: 250px;"></div>



Solution
As I mentioned in the 'How to work' section above, if you don't want a column to be stacked, set the stack parameter to null (or undefined).
The issue arises when you want to set them to not be stacked, as in reality, you're assigning each series to a stack, which is named after the corresponding stack index.
Wrong code from your question
series.forEach((serie, index) => {
  // index will 1, 2, ... 13 and not null
  serie.stack = shouldStack ? 'stackMe!' : index;
});

ECharts displays the stacks in alphabetical order, so your series with the stack property 13 will appear in the last position. Although they don't appear to be stacked, this is because you have only added one series to each stack. In the 'How to work' section, I wrote you two stacks as example so you can see how the unique-name principle of stacking works.
Successfully - set stack to null if you don't want stacking
series.forEach((serie) => {
  serie.stack = shouldStack ? 'stackUniquNameHere' : null;
});

